# Spans not aligned properly on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two spans being not aligned properly on Firefox :

```css
.foo {
  padding : 3px 8px;
}
```

```html
<span class='foo' style='background-color:blue; font-family: Arial'>FOO</span>
<span class='foo' style='background-color: green; font-family: Lato'>BLAH</span>
```

It's perfectly fine on all the IE and Chrome browsers, but for some reasons on Firefox, the left span isn't aligned with the right span. It looks like the right span is one px too much towards the bottom.

If I remove the foo class, it's working, but why in the world is firefox not aligning these spans properly ?

Comment: I see perfectly aligned in firefox v43.0.4

Comment: Note that paddings doesn't work in an `inline` element, you should change to `inline-block` or `block` to make work it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude horizontal paddings do work with inline boxes (but I agree about vertical padding)

Comment: @user3790069 no, paddings doesn't work with inline elements, neither horizontal nor vertical. Almost in the standard W3C coding, if it works in chrome or IE, I don't know, but it's not the normal and correct behaviour

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude https://jsfiddle.net/22c03k2q/ it works in FF too and it is the correct behaviour described in the W3C documentation

Comment: I think the bug comes from the Lato font-family !

Comment: I'm flipping!!! What the hell!! https://jsfiddle.net/22c03k2q/1/ I don't understand anything. Since the paddings are applied to inline elements? And why that's strange behaviour? See the fiddle, the padding top is in negative offset with the body.... Now, I have the ass reverted (el culo torcido in spanish)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude BTW [vertical margins do work on inline boxes too](https://jsfiddle.net/22c03k2q/4/). :)

Comment: can you note the padding top in my fiddle? Is outside the document, with a negative offset.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes. The vertical paddings are drawn around inline boxes, but they don't influence the height of these inline boxes (`line-height` does) and don't move them, that's why you see this "negative offset"

Comment: While I do see the differences between the two boxes (the right one is larger on my computer) I don't understand why padding would have anything to do with it. The difference is there too if I don't apply padding. Oh, and it happens in Chromium as well as SeaMonkey. So I think it may have something to do with the Lato font, yes. And you know, the funny thing is I don't even have Lato installed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox isn't playing well with Lato. Adapting the font-family to match each other (or not using Lato) would solve the problem.